# How to pass variable in hive query reading from file as table name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hive, hql

I am writing shell script which will read a table name from a file, and pass table name to hive query.

But i assume `$` not recognized in hive.

Any idea how can I pass the variable in hive query?

> Error : can not recognize input near $i

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Input file
ifile="/tmp/table.txt" 

if [[ -f "$ifile" ]]
then
  while IFS= read -r i
    hive -e "show create table $i"
  done <"$ifile"
fi
```

**$cat table.txt**

```
office.empoyee
office.department
office.floor
```

Comment: Please don't edit questions and incorporate answers. It causes the question to lose context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all that is missing here is the `do` after the `while` line:

```
if [[ -f "$ifile" ]]
then
  while IFS= read -r i
  do
    hive -e "show create table ${i}"
  done <"$ifile"
fi
```

Comment: problem is with hive statement not able to recognise $ , any other way to pass it .

Comment: With the proper syntax, `$i` will be expanded to the value in the file and `hive` will never see it

Comment: Try re-typing the line `hive -e "show create table ${i}"`

Comment: i dont think you need the {}